# Creating lucee spreadsheet -

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet, cfml, lucee

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet via Lucee and https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-spreadsheet

Got the mapping working correctly and using the following code

```
data = QueryNew( "First,Last", "VarChar,VarChar", [ [ "Susi","Sorglos" ], [ "Frumpo","McNugget" ] ] );
spreadsheet = New spreadsheetLibrary.Spreadsheet();
workbook = spreadsheet.workbookFromQuery( data );
path = "C:\Inetpub\pathtosavefileto\owners\owners.xls";
spreadsheet.write( workbook, path, true );
```

It creates a 0 byte file but I get the following error

```
Lucee 5.2.6.60 Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)
Message org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils
Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
C:\Inetpub\pathtocfc\spreadsheetLibrary\Spreadsheet.cfc: line 1662
1660: lock name="#arguments.filepath#" timeout=5{
1661: var outputStream = CreateObject( "java", "java.io.FileOutputStream" ).init( arguments.filepath );
1662: arguments.workbook.write( outputStream );
1663: outputStream.flush();
1664: }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm your `/lib` folder has everything listed here: https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-spreadsheet/tree/master/lib ?

Comment: Yep its got everything in it

Comment: just re uploaded it again and still the same

Comment: Servlet Container - Apache Tomcat/8.5.16 
Java - 1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation) 64bit

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? `Dump( server.java.version )`.

Comment: Puzzling. There have been some similar issues reported with certain builds of Lucee: https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-spreadsheet/issues/195 Can you try with the latest version?

Comment: ok will give that a go and report back

Comment: hmmm lucee not updateing now

Comment: Lucee 5.2.6.60 Error (expression) 
Message Can't cast Complex Object Type Struct to String 
Detail Use Built-In-Function "serialize(Struct):String" to create a String from Struct

Comment: ok - updated Lucee manually and its solved the problem! Thanks for your help